# apple distribution certificates expiring in a month

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have a question my distribution certificates are going to expire in 30 days. No as far as I know those apps which are on Appstore won't get affected by this but my client has more than 50 apps on App Store. Every app has push notifications as well so I have created them pem files as well. So after expiration do I have to create pem files again?  I am concerned about Push Notifications, will they work even after this distribution certificate expires?

Comment: yes you have to Generate .pem file again and upload it to server. this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706656/how-to-renew-push-notification-services-certificate

Comment: actually I have some 60 odd applications and what you are saying means I have to create pem files for all of them

Comment: I have seen the above mentioned link. I must say I was not willing to believe that I have to create pem files for all my apps. One more thing do I have to repeat this every time,  because certificates will be expired again?

Comment: yes you need to do every time.

Comment: this sounds really weird. Doing it again and again when all the apps are on AppStore. Currently we have 65 apps on Store and it will increase with the passage of time. But thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

The push certificate cannot be renewed. You have to create a new one.

The push notification certificate is not part of the application build. Therefore for push to continue working you only have to create a new certificate and deploy the p12 file (or whatever other format you are using) at your server. You don't have to submit a new version of your app.

See this - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106036/renew-push-certificate-and-keep-current-app-store-app-working)