# Will generating new APNS certificate invalidate existing active certificate

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

We already have existing valid APNS certificate for push notifications in production which will be expiring in a month. If I generate new certificate now, will it make existing certificate invalid?

*Note:- I want to do this to get rid of window between the time certificate expires and generating a new certificate, so that push notifications do not get missed.*
*Edit:- With current architecture, it is not easy to immediately start using new certificate*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Renew Push Notification Services Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706656/how-to-renew-push-notification-services-certificate)

Comment: @vinaykrishnan I went through the the link you shared, but I could not still see the answer which I want. As certificate being used is still valid and if I generate new one, will it make existing certificate used by my server invalid causing push notifications to stop being sent to apple server?

Comment: No, generating new APNS certificate will not invalidate existing active certificate, and it will not effect on your current push notification functionality.

as Push notification certificates not the part of your build, you just need to change certificates on your server only.

Comment: @Pankaj Can you please add this as an answer?

Comment: @deepakraut sure!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, generating a new APNS certificate will not invalidate your existing active certificate, and it will not affect your current push notification functionality. Push notification certificates are not part of your build, so you only need to change certificates on your server.

You can also check this answer and discussion to better understand how this works:
[Renew Push certificate and keep current App Store App working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106036/renew-push-certificate-and-keep-current-app-store-app-working)